# How do I GET REQUEST XML data to a webservice with Postman?

Tags: xml, web-services, postman

I want GET REQUEST an XML request to a web service using `Postman`. However, when I check the available request formats, I only see options for form-data, `x-www-form-urlencoded`, raw, and binary.

How do I `POST` an `XML` `request` to a `web service` with `Postman`?

Comment: Nupe, it was opposite of that question using GET Method Not Post Method

Answer (score 1):

Use the raw format, after selecting that, select XML type from dropbox.

Comment: It show Server Error 500, I am Using the WSDL url like api.rlcarriers.com/sandbox/BillOfLadingService.asmx?WSDL=

Comment: This is the soap request, This URL may help you:
https://learning.getpostman.com/docs/postman/sending-api-requests/making-soap-requests/

Answer (score 1):

In **Body** > Select  **Raw** > Choose **XML** and write your XML data....

[image]

Comment: It show Server Error 500, I am Using the WSDL url like https://api.rlcarriers.com/sandbox/BillOfLadingService.asmx?WSDL=

Comment: May the API is not working properly, Or you are missing any headers or something, Do you have proper doc about this API>